# Does $\int e^{dx}$ makes sense?

Tags: integration

I know this is quite weird or it does not make much sense, but I was wondering, does $\int e^{dx}$ has any meaning or whether it makes sense at all? If it does means something, can it be integrated and what is the result?

Comment: Makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think it should make sense - what is your intuition that it might?

Comment: Not a single reason why it makes sense. It just popped up in my head when I was having lunch and I spent the last several hours whether it makes sense at all with no result, so I posted it here.

Comment: I agree with the comments and answers, but [check this out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_II:_geometric_integral).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The differential in an integral is essentially a symbolic way to show on which variable you integrate and is not to be taken as a factor. With this in mind,

$$\int e^{dx}$$ is just syntactically unparsable, in the same way as

$$\sin(x=(+$$

Answer (score 0):

Well it makes sense when you think about it one way and it doesn't when you think about it another way...First of all $dx$ is supposed to be extremely close to $0$ so (as J.G. said)
that's going to equal $1+dx$ which is essentially 1. On the other hand its not supposed to make sense cuz $e^{dx}$ it self doesn't have a value (you can't take it as $1$ because $dx$ is not $0$ and you can't take it as a value because $dx$ is super small) so how can you actually add up infinite amounts of this...I mean integration is essentially zooming in so that the area under a graph is actually infinite amounts of small rectangles but with the $dx$ difference you can't zoom in infinitely because there will always be the difference...I mean you can zoom in on $e^2$ because it has a fixed value...but you can't do that for $e^{dx}$ because $dx$ doesn't really have a well defined value

Hope you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

I agree, that formally it make no sense, but as lunch exercise in mathematical fantasy , if we can give some sense to $(dx)^n$ as some measure, then we can imagine $\int e^{dx}=\int \sum \frac{(dx)^n}{n!}$. Now the point is what is $(dx)^n$..

Answer (score 0):

Tool 1: Know, $\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{a^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}=\ln(a) $. Now, \begin{align*} 
\int e^{\mathrm{d}x}&=\int e^{\mathrm{d}x}-1+1\\
&=\int \frac{e^{\mathrm{d}x}-1}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x+1\\
&=\int \ln(e)\,\mathrm{d}x+1\\
&=x\ln(e)+1\\
&=x+1 +\text{constant}
\end{align*}